# 'coins of different sizes' or 'coins in different sizes'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

The original text is

> they invented coins **of** different sizes

Is it OK if I say this instead?

> they invented coins **in** different sizes

Comment: "invented coins"? Never heard such a thing. Maybe you mean "minted"?

Comment: @user3169 Coins are not naturally occurring, somebody invented them

Comment: @DCShannon This really needs more context, but just changing coin sizes would not be considered an *invention*, unless there was a specific goal stated (why different sizes would be useful). Maybe if they were the *first* coins. For example, if you can buy 27" TVs, then if someone starts making 50" TVs, they would not be considered an invention.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's okay. You'll be understood, and I doubt many would even pause upon hearing it.

That being said, I think "of different sizes" is the more natural and common way to put it, or perhaps "of different size".

See this related English SE question: [Different size or different sizes](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7820/70061)?

Also look at [this Google NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20different%20sizes%2C%20of%20different%20sizes&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20different%20sizes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cof%20different%20sizes%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bof%20different%20sizes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bof%20Different%20Sizes%3B%2Cc0) for "of different sizes", "of different size", "in different sizes", and "in different size".